# What does "fakesource" refer to in a python pdb debugging session?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm trying to drill into the internals of my Bokeh application to see how an AjaxDataSource works under the hood to gain some inspiration to generalize a remote source for my application through a custom extension of the necessary base classes.

I was able to step in a good amount of pdb earlier in the function but I hit a limit where the debugger landed on fakesource like shown below when drilling into the `circle` function. Here's the python source below...

```
def modify_doc1(doc):

    # get model data from Flask
    url    = "http://localhost:8080/sendModelData/"
    pdb.set_trace()
    source = AjaxDataSource( data             = dict( x=[] , y=[] ) ,
                             data_url         = url       ,
                             polling_interval = 5000      ,
                             mode             = 'replace' ,
                             method           = 'GET'     )
    # plot the model data
    plot = figure( )
    plot.circle( 'x' , 'y' , source=source , size=2 )
    doc.add_root(column(plot))


> C:\MyBokehApp\flask_embedjsonroute.py(43)modify_doc1()
-> plot.circle( 'x' , 'y' , source=source , size=2 )
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> C:\MyBokehApp\fakesource(2)circle()
(Pdb) n
> C:\MyBokehApp\fakesource(3)circle()
(Pdb) n
> C:\MyBokehApp\fakesource(4)circle()
(Pdb) n
> C:\MyBokehApp\fakesource(5)circle()
(Pdb) n
--Return--
```

I'm curious what this is communicating exactly? I've seen `fakepath` in an html file input context but what does `fakesource` mean with python source and the debugger? Is this saying I'm hitting a binary implementation or assembly code or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `plot.circle` is a function that has been generated at run-time by the `bokeh` library.  To generate this function, `bokeh` has created some source code on the fly and compiled it into a python function.

When compiling such source a *filename* can be given to indicate its origin.  This allows tools such as `pdb` to load that source in order to show it to you.  In this case, `bokeh` has set this *filename* to `fakesource`.

(The code responsible for this is `bokeh.plotting.helpers` if you wish to see it yourself)

Comment: Interesting, so just to confirm we're talking about something in this source [helpers.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.5dev14/bokeh/plotting/helpers.py) am I correct?

Comment: No we are not .. but its the code in `helpers.py` that will dynamically compile functions at run time.

Comment: Aha, gotcha, looks like it's brought onboard at
`func_code = compile(func_text, "fakesource", "exec")`. Looks like I somehow mistakenly searched bokeh source for fakepath and got mislead with no hits there ><.